# Using part of a variable as bool

Tags: c++, performance, bit

Let's say memory is precious, and I have a class with a `uint32_t` member variable `ui` and I know that the values will stay below 1 million. The class also hase some `bool` members.

1. Does it make sense to use the highest (highest 2,3,..) bit(s) of `ui` in order to save memory, since `bool` is 1 byte?
2. If it does make sense, what is the most efficient way to get the highest (leftmost?) bit (or 2nd)? I read a few old threads and there seems to be disagreement about using inline ASM or some sort of shift.

Comment: C bitfield syntax is fully supported in C++.

Comment: [Bit fields](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) are probably the best solution, until you can manage to have a better optimized implementation than the compiler.

Comment: `struct A { bool a:1; uint32_t b: 31;};`

Comment: Memory is precious but likely not *that* much.

Comment: @VictorGubin that will align `b` because it is not of the same type as `a`. Maybe a compiler-specific member backing directive would help.

Comment: @Quentin An experiment https://godbolt.org/z/E3f4vT (not sure about MS VC++)

Comment: @VictorGubin huh, well that helps things quite a bit then. Cppreference just says that bitfield packing is implementation-defined, I don't know where I got the idea that it depended on the types of consecutive members.

Comment: Regarding Bit fields / `bitset`s: Instead of combining multiple variables into one, would it make sense to have a large `bitset` (e.g. `std::bitset<2000000>`) to combine the boolean variable from all the objects? Assuming the objects are in an array and I know that position, the position in the `bitset` could be made to correlate to that. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit dangerous to use part of the bits as bool. The thing is that the way the numbers are kept in binary, makes it harder to maintain that keeping mechanism correct.

Negative numbers are kept as a complement of positive. Check [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/239036/how-are-negative-signed-values-stored#:%7E:text=In%20most%20implementations%20that%20you,numbers%20is%20called%20one%27s%20complement.&text=The%20one%27s%20complement%20of%20an,all%20its%20bits%20flipped%2C%20basically.) for more explanation. You may assign number to be 10 and then setting bool bit from false to true, and the number may turn out to become huge negative number as a result.

As for getting if n-th bit is 0 or 1 you can use this, where 0-th bit is the right most:

```
int nth_bit(int a, int n){
    return a & (1 << n);
}
```

It will return 0 or 1 identifying the n-th bit.

Comment: Thanks. I realize using a variable for two purposes comes with drawbacks, so I'm actually not convinced this is a good idea myself. And thanks for your solution, but I would think that for a 4-byte variable, your solution requires a lot of shifts. :/

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the memory is in fact precious, you should look deeper.

1,000,000 uses only 20 bits. This is less that 3 bytes. So you can allocate 3 bytes to keep your value and up to four booleans. Obviously, access will be a bit more complicated, but you save 25% of memory!

If you know that the values are below 524,287, for example, you can save another 15% by packing it (with bool) into 20 bits :)

Also, keeping bool in a separate array (as you said in a comment) would kill performance if you need to access the value and a corresponding bool simultaneously because they are far apart and will likely never be in a cache.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As I've said elsewhere I have come to realize that while this has been suggested to me by a C++ veteran, combining variables does not make sense in my case. The value itself is also accessed frequently (the `bool` not so much), so each time I'd have to calculate the corresponding value, which does not come for free. :/

Comment: @Markstar - eternal dilemma: save time or save RAM? :)